# Ruby AWS::S3::S3Object.find always returns NoSuchKey exception

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3

I am trying to test for the existence of an image before I attempt to get its url, because if I just used the "url_for" method that it does not throw an error in the event that a resource is not available.

However, I can get a valid url from url_for, but I get a NoSuchKey exception using the "find" method with the EXACT SAME PARAMETERS. This is taking too long. Does this just plain not work?

Update: Switched to AWS-S3, now using code below:

```
bucket = "my_amazon_bucket"
key = "my_amazon_key"

begin
  s3 = RightAws::S3Interface.new(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
  # This will trigger the exception if this image doesn't exist.
  s3.head(bucket,key)
  retval = s3.get_link(bucket,key)
rescue RightAws::AwsError => bang
  puts bang.message + ": #{bucket} : #{key}"
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I struggled with the 'aws-s3' gem. Seems old and unsupported. I'm having a much better time with the 'S3' gem:

https://github.com/qoobaa/s3

Others are using 'right_aws'

https://github.com/rightscale/right_aws

Comment: Thanks Seph, I did switch to right_aws yesterday and was able to figure it out. One shortcoming that I can see with it though is that you can't use the same object to both check the existence of a key and to create a non-public url. Their "get_link" method, like its analog in aws-s3, doesn't throw an Exception because it just uses a local algorithm to create the url. However, there is a "head" method in the same interface that *will* throw the exception if a key isn't found, without the overhead of retrieving the whole object, so that's what I used.

Comment: Thank you for the accept(my first). I will be looking into using your strategy for checking the existence of a file in S3 without the overhead of retrieving it. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: You're welcome and my pleasure seph, I posted a bit of code up there to for you.